# Test my app on a Tablet ICS emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I'm trying to test my app on a Tablet ICS emulator, but I don't know exactly how to do that...
It's important that the OS will be ICS (or above).

Thanx upfront.

Comment: You might consider elaborating a bit more on "I don't know exactly how to do that".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Eclipse:

Window -> AVD Manager -> Target ( >= API Level 14 ).

On resolution use something like: 1280x800 (Galaxy Tab 10.1).

Then use that emulator.

Comment: Thanx, but how do I change between landscape and portrait mode?